# ajax cross browser code compatibility

Tags: jquery, django, cross-browser, jsonp

I made a website in which the backend is in django and the front end uses php . Since i wad developing this in localhost so there were two servers `localhost` and `localhost:8000`
I had to use ajax cross browser codes in ajax calls and in django to make the sending and receiving of data possible . Now i am using a server in which i can keep both django backend and php front end . So my question is this possible that now when they are in same server can that code of ajax cross browser be used and ajax calls would run properly ? Or i have to make a new code? my ajax cross browser code for php is like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "localhost:8000/bo/get_p_uai/",
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'jsonp',              
    success: function (data) {
    var agg =data['p_uai_agg'];
    //alert(agg);
    $('#bumkush').val(agg);

    forward_me();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still return JSONP from a request to the same domain, but you'll need to set `crossDomain` to `false`

Comment: and if i set cross domain to false then would the would changes i did django for cross domain . will it return me back the values ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would have to see what you're talking about on the Django side of things.